# Predicting number of events with 99.9% probability based on tests of four devices

Tags: probability

I've never taken a stats course so I really don't know where to begin on this.

I am using microcontroller that according to the datasheet, has a Flash memory that can be reprogrammed a minimum of 10,000 times, with 100,000 times being a more typical number.

These numbers seem low to me (based on other devices using a similar technology which claim lifetimes of an order of magnitude higher), so I decided to take one of our products and do destructive testing on it.  I started testing last Friday night and it is already up to 600,000 events without an error (as determined by calculating a 16-bit CRC over the 4K bytes of data test being Flashed).  Based on this device far surpassing the "typical" value in the datasheet, I have started tests on three more devices.

So at some point I will have a failure value for all four devices.  How can I use that data to predict an expected lifetime x for the device with a 99.9% certainty?  (Not sure if I am saying that right, what I mean is that only 0.1% of devices will fail before x events).

Comment: The traditional way you could do this is through hypothesis testing. This will allow you to test whether the plausibility that the lifetime is equal to some value, say 10,000 times.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing

Comment: You have to make strong assumptions about the lifetimes.  Without them, you would need to test approximately 3/(0.1%) = 3000 devices.  For example, suppose 1% of the devices have a relatively rare defect that causes them to fail after 100 reprogrammings.  Your chance of encountering one of them during your testing of only four devices is approximately 4%: pretty low.  Thus, *based on the data alone,* you can have very little confidence that such defects don't exist in the population of microcontrollers.

Comment: @whuber - is my answer consistent with your point about assumptions?

Comment: @David Yes it is.  Good work.  I was thinking along the lines of borrowing strength from other datasets or knowledge about failure modes and distributions derived from similar devices.  Such information could justify a Bayesian estimate, too.

Comment: It may be there is a significant variation in chips from different wafers (batches), but low variation within a batch.  This means that if the four chips are all from the same batch, it may give a misleading view of the lifetime of a chip selected at random from the whole production run.  It may be the low lifetime quoted is because there is occasionally a bad batch and it is easier to quote a low life expectancy than to detect the bad batches.  If your chips are all from the same batch, it may not be possible to estimate the true population lifetime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@whuber makes an important point about assumptions,

It is common to assume that failure occurs either because a part is defective or because it has worn out. This means that there are two processes causing failure, and defective units fail shortly after deployment whereas wearing out happens over time. It is difficult (or impossible) to justify parameterizing both of these processes if $n=4$.

**Case 1**

For a simple case, assume that defective units can be eliminated (e.g. by an initial screening or 'burn in'), and all units fail due to a constant wearing process. This assumption may be valid since the data sheet says that the minimum expected lifetime is $10,000$ events. One might model this process as an exponential distribution:

Example: assume that your four test units fail after $[5,10,20,40]x10^{5}$ reprogrammings. You can find the maximum likelihood estimate for the exponential distribution in R:

```
library(MASS)
fitdistr(c(5, 10, 20, 40)*1e+5, 'exponential')
lambda <- fitdistr(c(5, 10, 20, 40)*1e+5, 'exponential')$estimate
```

To find the time during which only 1/1000 units will fail, estimate the 0.1th quantile of this distribution.

```
qexp(0.001, lambda)
```

In this example, the result is an expected lifetime of 1875.

*edit* As whuber points out, $n=4$ is still to small for this problem, because it is very difficult to estimate small probabilities, and distribution tails are very sensitive to assumptions about the probability distributions used to model the data, and to the data itself.

Since you have good prior knowledge from the product datasheet, you could incorporate this information into your analysis as a prior on lambda. The gamma distribution is a conjugate prior, $\lambda\sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta)$, but I can not find a parameterization appropriate to the prior information, with $\text{median}\simeq 100,000$, $P(Y<10,000)\simeq 0)$ and nonzero density above $10,000$. Once you determine the model to use, it would be worth asking a separate question.

**Case 2**

If you assume that failure is caused either by defect or by wear, you could consider the Weibull and Generalized Exponential distributions (Gupta and Kunda 1999, 2001, 2007). The field of survival analysis provides many options, but as whuber points out, $n=4$ is insufficient to justify a model other than, perhaps, the single parameter exponential.

---

[Gupta, R. D. and Kundu, D. (1999). Generalized exponential distributions", Australian and New Zealand Journal of Statistics, vol. 41, 173 - 188.](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~kundu/paper47.pdf)

[Gupta, R. D. and Kundu, D. (2001), Generalized exponential distributions: different methods of estimation", Journal of Statistical Computation and Simulation. vol. 69, 315-338](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~kundu/paper62.pdf).

[Gupta, R. D. and Kundu, D. 2007. Generalized Exponential Distribution: existing results and some recent developments. Journal of Statistical Planning and Inference](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~kundu/paper113.pdf)

Comment: +1 for the R code illustrating fast solution of the problem

Comment: @David if $n=4$ is too small to justify most models, why is it enough to justify *any* model?

Comment: @whuber my point was that, given $n=4$, it might be most appropriate to fit a single parameter model. I can see your point though. Perhaps it would help to incorporate his prior knowledge into a gamma prior with $P(Y<100,000)=0.5$ and $P(Y<10,000)\simeq 0)$?

Comment: @David I don't know enough about this particular situation to comment on any specific proposal.  The point I am making is that there is no magic in statistics that will generate "99.9% certainty" from a sample of four.  A single-parameter model might fit beautifully but anybody would be foolish to rely on a 99.9% CI or percentile estimated with it *unless* they had substantial, *independent* evidence that the model is appropriate.

Comment: @whuber I also don't know much about failure analysis and never think about such small probabilities, but I know that tail probabilities are much more sensitive and difficult to estimate - is that the reason for your concern?

Comment: @David I didn't plead ignorance concerning the *subject matter* :-)  I just don't know what additional information the OP has, so I have no idea whether your gamma prior is reasonable.  (Choice of prior is a big deal with this small sample.)  The concern is only indirectly about high uncertainties attached to tail probabilities.  More fundamentally it's about the model itself: if you use a bad model for the failure distribution, you will likely get bad (or awful) estimates.  How, then, can you tell whether the model is appropriate?  Not by testing just four units!

Comment: @David, thank you for your answer.  We do know that the failure will be due to the Flash memory "wearing out".  Any devices failing less than the minimum can be ignored and treated as burn-in failures.  I had one of the four fail with less than 100 events, but it was a "soft" failure and I restarted the test.  I am only interested in hard failures where retries are not possible.  Right now the counters on the four devices are approximately 721,000, 166,000, 166,000 and 172,000 so none have failed yet. (continued)

Comment: (continued from above)  I picked the number of 99.9% somewhat arbitrarily -- our current overall return rate for the product in the field after several months is between one and two percent, and I was just wanting to make sure this new process didn't contribute significantly to this return rate.  If I wanted to use your formula in R for other percentages (say 99.5, 99 and 98) I would just subsitute 0.005, 0.01 and 0.02 in the qexp line?

Comment: @David, I have installed R version 2.12.1.  Since you are using the MASS library, would "Modern Applied Statistics with S" be worthwhile for me to get (I notice there is an edition available for my Kindle DX), or would it be over my head since I have never taken a stats course?  Or do you recommend other book(s)?  (I do have an MS in computer science.)  Thanks.

Comment: @tcrosley yes, that is correct; MASS is one of the best books for learning R - I don't think that it would be over your head. I used MASS for the `fitdistr`, which provides a maximum likelihood estimate (MLE) of a distribution's parameters given data. So, if you are interested in the theory, use `?fitdistr` and read up on MLE. But you might want to consider comparing the fits of different distributions, perhaps contacting the manufacturer for additional data that could be used in a hierarchical model.

Comment: @David: Thanks --- (FIXED): [Modern Applied Statistics in S (and R) is available online here.](http://www.stat.ubc.ca/~d.lee/TA/2011/Texts/MASS.pdf)